# Java if statements only displaying the else statement

Tags: java, if-statement

Hey im coding a simple program for java and im having problems with my if and else statements.

```
Scanner coffee = new Scanner(System.in);
    String z = coffee.nextLine();
    if (z == "y")
        System.out.println("Great! Let's get started.");
    else if (z == "n")
        System.out.println("Come back next time, " + x + "." );
    else 
        System.out.println("Error please try again");
```

Where it only comes up with the else statement.

Comment: You cant compare strings with **==** in java

Comment: You are comparing references here so it is always printing "Error please try again".You should use .equals() method.

Answer (score 1):

Use `z.equals("n")` to compare strings in java